# Moment.js / moment-timezone: Format date with 'GMT-06:00' type date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to parse a date created with moment.js, with a timezone obtained from an API response of this type:

```
{
  "id": "MX",
  "name": "Mexico",
  "time_zone": "GMT-06:00"
}
```

I have a moment object created in react, but i need to change it's timezone to the one obtained by the API, in this example is "GMT-06:00".

For this i have this function:

```
setDateTimezone(date) {
    let timezone = this.state.siteData.time_zone;
    return moment(date).tz(timezone).format();
  }
```

It receives a moment object and it changes it timezone with tz.

However, this returns the following error:

> Moment Timezone has no data for GMT-06:00.

I need to somehow parse the API timezone format to one accepted by Moment, and create a new moment object with this new timezone.

Thanks a lot for your time, have a nice day.

Comment: See moment-timezone [docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/): _The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the `moment` constructor, but uses the last argument as a [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)._. See [`parseZone()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need moment-timezone for this.  Just use the `utcOffset` function from Moment.  It will ignore the letters, so you can just do this:

```js
moment(date).utcOffset('GMT-06:00').format()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the perfect world, you have a region timezone identifier rather than a static TZ like the one you have, because these are not DST aware nor understand politics of time. If your only option it to work with GMTxy format then you can use `Etc/GMTxy`, see the table below:

https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2017b/etcetera#L36-L42

And https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/offset/

So it would be something like:

```
const timezone = `Etc/GMT${parseInt(data.time_zone.replace(/GMT/, ''))}`
moment(date).tz(timezone).format()
```

(please  note i haven't tested that thoroughly)

Comment: Yes, but if a fixed offset is all there is, then actually they should use the `utcOffset` function from Moment.  You do not need moment-timezone for this.  Also, it will ignore the letters, so you can just `moment(date).utcOffset('GMT-06:00').format()` and it will work.

Comment: That makes sense, I was focusing on their own approach and didn't consider anything else. I think you should go for a full answer.

Comment: @MattJohnson please go for a full answer, your approach ended up working!